# Page View counter missing

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages, online, social-tag, sharepoint-news

I use social bar in some SharePoint online pages with  likes, comments, number of views, but now suddenly the total views counter has disappear.
Older pages have the data, buy news doesn't show total view counter.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Social Bar will appear on all modern SharePoint Online pages with the exception of the home page of a site. This visibility will be available to anyone that has been granted access to view the page.

You could use PowerShell to enable social bar for the site.

```
#Set Parameters
$AdminCenterURL="https://yourtenant-admin.sharepoint.com"
$SiteURL = "https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitecollectionName"

#Connect to SharePoint Online
Connect-SPOService -Url $AdminCenterURL -Credential (Get-Credential)

#Disable Social Bar on Site Pages
Set-SPOSite -Identity $SiteURL -SocialBarOnSitePagesDisabled $false
```